# SQL Table Decode from a SQL query

Tags: mysql

I have a sql query,

```
$sql = "select   
tbl_user.name,chat.from,chat.message,chat.to,chat.id,chat.sent,chat.recd  
from chat,tbl_user where (chat.to =   
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['chatuser'])."' AND recd = 0) and 
chat.from=tbl_user.user_id order by id ASC";
```

But i dont know how to create a table from this information. The above is
a select table syntax, but can anyone help me to make the above sql query
to a proper syntax, so that i can create the table.

Example, i need the ab0ve t0 like this

```
// sql to create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50),
reg_date TIMESTAMP
)";
```

Comment: Didn't understand anything from the question and tag only the `database` you are using not everything under the sun. Looks like you are using `mysql`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `CREATE TABLE new_tbl AS SELECT ...`

Read the documentation for MySql:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html

Comment: yes.. as i said i need t0 create a database with the ab0ve sql query.  Anyway thanks f0r y0ur help.. thanks BES